# Grouping lists in Python by specific same list values

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

Can anyone offer advice on how to find and group lists by certain list elements?

Below is an example which finds and groups same values in a sublist by comparing all list elements...

## Working example finding and grouping same values in a list:

```
L = #List of Vectors

# Example L[0] = [8.999999590709139, 164.00000059986633, 152.00000160567942]

d = defaultdict(list) # Group by same Vectors

for item in L:
    d[tuple(item)].append(item)

sv = sorted(d[x] for x in d)

print "No of same values found =”, len(sv)
```

## The working example above considers ALL items in the list for comparison, but how to consider finding and grouping same items by only the first three items of a list whilst keeping the list intact?

```
# Example L2[0] = [8.999999590709139, 164.00000059986633, 152.00000160567942, "Q","W","E","R","T","Y","3.14"]

# Example L2[1] = [8.999999590709139, 164.00000059986633, 152.00000160567942, "A","S","D","F","G","H","J"]

# len(L2[0]) = 10

# Find and group lists with same L2[i][0], L2[i][1], L2[i][2] values...

# Desired output - sortedlist = [[[1,2,3,"a","b","c"],[1,2,3,"d","e","f"]],[[3,4,5,"a","b","c"],[3,4,5,"d","e","f"]]]

#print sortedlist returns [[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3, 'd', 'e', 'f']], [[3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [3, 4, 5, 'd', 'e', 'f']]]

#print sortedlist[1] returns [[3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [3, 4, 5, 'd', 'e', 'f']]

#print sortedlist returns [1][2] [3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated...

Comment: `the first three items of a list` -> `my_list[:3]`

Comment: I've tried several approaches, for item in L:
    d[tuple(item[0],item[1],item[2)].append(item) etc...  Unfortunately not homework, I'm a qualified architect trying to model complex geometry using vectors and data!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to  jzk2...

```
 from collections import defaultdict

 d = defaultdict(list)

for item in L:
    d[tuple(item[:3])].append(item)

sortedL = sorted(d[x] for x in d)
```